# How to know which java version the Maven is using when build the project

Tags: java, maven

I would like to know if it's possible check which Java version my Maven is using to build the project.

1. The `JAVA_HOME` was set to JDK 1.8.
2. In pom.xml I have this properties configured:

```xml
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

I try figured out a way to **check it in mvn logs**, but I can't find whitch version was used.

How to know the Java version throught some kind of mvn logs.

I appretiate any support.

Comment: The first and simplest is to use: `mvn --version` will print out the information...If you like to check within the build your should check maven-enforcer-plugin like https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireJavaVersion.html

Comment: Furthermore I would suggest to use `<maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>` instead of the given properties...

Comment: Thanks khmarbaise

Answer (score 2):

In your command line if you run `mvn -v` it shows something like

```
Maven home: C:\maven\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 15.0.1, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\java\jdk-15.0.1
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you build the project, in command line it would use the JAVA_HOME setting, in IDE it would use IDE settings for the project, e.g. in IDEA, go to Project Settings page (File -> Project Structure), you can check the Project SDK & Project language level settings on "Project" & "Modules" page, that shows which SDK & language level the current project used.